# Limit of uniformly converging volume-preserving homeomorphisms

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, volume

**Definition** A continuous map $f\colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ is *volume-preserving* if, for every Borel set $V\subset\mathbb{R}^d$, $\mathcal{L}^d(V) = \mathcal{L}^d(f^{-1}(V))$.

I am wondering if the following holds:

> Suppose $f_n\colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ is a volume-preserving homeomorphism for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
> If $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, then $f$ is a volume-preserving
> homeomorphism.

So far, we know that $f$ is volume-preserving for the following reason. Let $\phi \in C_c^\infty$. Because $f_n$ is volume-preserving, $\int \phi\circ f_n\,dx = \int \phi\,dx$. As $f_n \to f$ uniformly, one can show that $\int \phi\circ f_n\,dx \to \int \phi \circ f\,dx$. Now we know that $\int \phi \circ f\,dx = \int \phi\,dx$, and so $f$ is volume-preserving.

Comment: Is this the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @DominiqueR.F. It's actually not even clear to me that $\int\phi\circ f_n\to\int\phi\circ f$. Do we have an actual proof of that, or are we just taking it as obvious?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I have made a more-or-less thorough search and have found no written proof of this result. It is stated (but not proved) in Hofer and Zehnder's _Hamiltonian dynamics and symplectic invariants_ that it is true if we only assume _locally_ uniform convergence. Maybe this is considered folklore by researchers in the field... I have a proof of the uniform convergence case, but it is far from obvious (in my humble opinion...). I will post it when I have some time to spare (probably tomorrow).

Comment: @DominiqueR.F. Thanks. As long as you agree it's not obvious there's no need to show me the proof; I'm willing to believe you. Was just concerned that we were taking it to be so obvious it didn't require proof.

Comment: Preserving volume is a local property (because volume [form] is local), so if uniform convergence is enough, so is local uniform convergence. But I'm confused: what is the question, exactly? You are asking about a fact and then you give a proof. Are you asking about correctness of the proof? About the unstated gap in the proof?

Comment: @tomasz: the question is asking to prove that $f^{-1}$exists and is continuous. It would appear that this is really difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This statement is not correct, the limit might not be a homeomorphism. Here is a sketch of an example in the plane: Pick a sequence of concentric circles $C_n$ of radius $1/n$ centered at $0$, let $D_n$ be the disk bounded by $C_n$, and $A_n$ the annulus between $C_n$ and $C_{n+1}$. Now pick a corresponding sequence of nested ellipses $E_n$, with $E_1 = C_1$ the unit circle, such that the area enclosed by $E_n$ is the same as the one enclosed by $C_n$, and such that the ellipses converge to a non-trivial interval $I$, e.g., $I = [-1/2, 1/2] \times \{0\}$. Let $F_n$ be the domain bounded by the ellipse $E_n$, and let $B_n$ be the topological annulus between $E_n$ and $E_{n+1}$. Then $F_n$ has the same area as $D_n$, and $B_n$ has the same area as $A_n$. Pick a sequence of orientation-preserving diffeomorphisms $\phi_n : E_n \to C_n$ with $\phi_1 = \textrm{id}$. By a classical result there exist area-preserving maps $g_n: F_n \to D_n$ (ellipse to disk) and $h_n: B_n \to A_n$ (elliptical annulus to round annulus) with boundary values given by $\phi_n$ and $\phi_{n+1}$. We also define $h_0 = \textrm{id}$ outside of the unit disk $C_1 = E_1$. Now define $f_n$ to agree with $h_k$ for $0 \le k < n$ outside of $E_n$, and with $g_n$ inside of $E_n$. Then it is easy to check that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to an area-preserving map $f$ of the plane which maps the whole interval $I$ to the point $0$.

Comment: Hello Lukas, thanks for taking the time to come up with the construction. Does the classical result mentioned in your answer guarantees that g_n or h_n is a homeomorphism? If so, could you kindly include a reference to that result?

Comment: @ZilinJ. Yes, they guarantee homeomorphic solutions. I have not found the exact statement, but it follows from theorems of Dacorogna and Moser in http://caa.epfl.ch/publications/22-Dacorogna-Moser1990.pdf, and also from an earlier weaker result by Banyaga in http://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?pid=ens-001:1974:20::57 (but that one is in French.) In this special case there is a lot of freedom of choice in the construction, so it is conceivable that you could do this directly (though I have not tried myself.)